# How to obtain CameraInfo Message

Tags: ros, simulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am doing this robot simulation on the UDK/UsarSim and have been able to publish image from the Robot Camera in the simulator to the ROS System. Then I want to use this image to perform SLAM using the V-Slam from willow garage. The problem is that the V-Slam node also subscribe to the CameraInfo Message. So my question is how to obtain the Camera Info Message from the USARSim/UDK?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52054/how-to-obtain-camerainfo-message/) by [ROS_NOOB_CYBORG](https://answers.ros.org/users/3275/ros_noob_cyborg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-01-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kr1zz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4727/kr1zz/) on 2013-09-30**:
Did you use USARSimROS to interface USARSim with ROS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Camera Info Message will not be published by USARSim, it describes the distortion of the Camera. What it is supposed to contain, can be found in the [Camera Info Message Api](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html)

> If the camera is uncalibrated, the matrices D, K, R, P should be left
> zeroed out. In particular, clients may assume that K[0] == 0.0  indicates an
> uncalibrated camera.

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROS_NOOB_CYBORG](https://answers.ros.org/users/3275/ros_noob_cyborg/) on 2013-01-13**:
Okay thanks for the information. Another question I want to ask is how you get the information regarding the "Header"?

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-11-04**:
Can you able to successfully able to work with UsarsimRos?